# Como eu posso fazer um split de uma string por ponto e vírgula e pegar o valor de cada posição após o while?

Tags: c, c++, string, parse

Como eu posso fazer um *split* de uma string por ponto e vírgula e pegar o valor de cada posição após o `while` ?

Exemplo:

```
result[0] //casa result[1] //carro
```

Meu código:

```
char str[] ="test;car;bar;mouse";
        char * pch;

        string result;

        pch = strtok (str,";");
        while (pch != NULL)
        {

          result += pch;
          printf ("%s\n",pch);
          pch = strtok (NULL, ";");
        }



     printf("value by position 0\n", result[0]);
```

Comment: Mas não é C++? Por que então está programado em C?

Comment: Batatei colocando C++. Obrigado amigo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esse código não é C++, é C, se se acha que está aprendendo C++, está enganado, só porque compila em C++ não quer dizer que seja C++. Se quiser fazer em C++ tem a opção aqui que é muito mais segura porque a biblioteca já fornece mecanismos adequados:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    vector<string> strings;
    istringstream texto("test;car;bar;mouse");
    string token;    
    while (getline(texto, token, ';')) {
        cout << token << endl;
        strings.push_back(token);
    }
    cout << "value by position 0 " << strings[0];
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/2TAzRN). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/@maniero/Splitcpp). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/String/Split.cpp).

Answer (score 1):

Pode declarar um multi array de char `result[5][10]` em que tem 5 linhas de strings que pode ter um tamanho maximo de 10 caracteres em cada linha.
Este é um exemplo muito siples, poderá fazer tambem de forma dinamica a alocação de memoria, fazer `char** result` e `realloc`\ `malloc` à medida que precisar de mais espaço.

Fica um exemplo de como podia resolver o seu problema:

```
char str[] ="test;car;bar;mouse";
char * pch;
pch = strtok (str,";");
char result[5][10];//declara multi array com 5 linhas e 10 caracteres maximo por linha
int i=0;
while (pch != NULL)
{
     strcpy(result[i++], pch);// a cada linha envia a String pch para result
     printf ("%s\n",pch);
     pch = strtok (NULL, ";");
}

printf("value by position 0 %s\n", result[0]);
```

Comment: Era isso mesmo que eu estava querendo fazer, muito obrigado Fábio.